# PHP and Ruby with Docker

Tags: php, ruby, docker

is possible to run two web apps at the same time, one using PHP the other using Ruby, each one on a Docker container ?

Comment: Your question might be better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Should be no problem. Normally you have one App per container.
You could create a Docker container for your PHP server and a container for your Ruby server.

You need to choose different ports, because by default, both will run on port 80 or 443 and then it should work

Answer (score -2):

Docker is designed to run one software, if you want to run more than one, you need a tool like supervisor, s6, daemontools, check the doc for supervisor

https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: The question already mentions "each one on a Docker container", so multiple containers?